# get data from db, save only the names in an array and use that array outside of foreach loop - Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

I want to get some data from my model. I only need the names from the products and nothing else. I want to save those names in an array and use that array in my blade.

```
 public function productPDF()
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        $products = [];
        foreach ($input['product_id'] as $products_id) {
            $products[] = Products::where('id', $product_id)->where('customer_id', Auth::user()->customers_id)->get();
        }
```

and in my blade:

```
 @foreach($products $product)
        <span>{{ $product->name }} | </span>
 @endforeach
```

if I do a : {{ $product}} in my foreach, then I get all the data from my product.  Like id, name, customers_id, created_at ....

But I only want the name and I don't know why $product->name won't work and why I get a MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

Can anyone help me there?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
 @foreach($products as $product)
    <span>{{ $product->name }} | </span>
 @endforeach
```

Also, with `foreach ($input['product_id'] as $products_id) {` you're creating multiple queries which is bad. Use [`whereIn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses) method. You can try something like this:

```
$products = Products::whereIn('id', $input['product_id'])->where('customer_id', Auth::user()->customers_id)->get();
```